# Como faço para setar uma lista de imagens no listview -> imageview a partir da url da página?

Tags: java, android, listview

O problema é que sempre que tem uma imagem nova na pagina especifica eu tenho que atualizar a aplicação com a nova URL da imagem setada na página.

Answer (score -2):

Tem várias api's,  uma API bem simples é o Picasso:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://myimage.png").into(mImageView);
```

Comment: Você terá que fazer um notify da sua lista..., Assim terá refresh da lista